# boost function bind compiled with a conversion error

Tags: c++, boost, bind

I have the following code

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

class Foo {    
    public:
    int getIfoo();
};

int Foo::getIfoo() {
    return 5;
}

int main () {

    boost::function<int (Foo)> getIntFoo;
    getIntFoo = boost::bind( &Foo::getIfoo, _1 );

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile with the following command `g++ TestBoostBind.cpp` I've got the following error

```
/includes/boost_1_60_0/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:35:36: error: invalid conversion from ‘const Foo*’ to ‘Foo*’ [-fpermissive]
         BOOST_MEM_FN_RETURN (u.*f_)();
                             ~~~~~~~^~
```

I'm confused about the source of the error whether it's originally from my code or the boost library. Does anyone know what the error means and how to fix it? I use g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0 and boost.1.60

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When binding to a member function, the first argument needs to be a *pointer* or a *reference* to the object to call the function on. It specifically can't be a value (an actual object instance). The `boost::bind` function have special cases for these two alternatives to generate the correct objects. It does *not* have any special case for passing by value.

Therefore you need to define `getIntFoo` as a function taking a *pointer* to `Foo`:

```
boost::function<int (Foo*)> getIntFoo;
```

Or a *reference*:

```
boost::function<int (Foo&)> getIntFoo;
```

Comment: Do you know why it also works when changing the type to `boost::function<int(Foo&)>` or leaving it as in the original snippet adding `const` to `int getIfoo()`? Is this some magic inside `boost::bind`?

Comment: @lubgr References could be used as well. I updated the answer about this with more details about `boost::bind` (and the answer is that yes it's some kind of "magic" inside `boost::bind` and its *specializations*).

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! I'm still wondering though why `boost::function<int(Foo)>` works with a const-qualified `int getIfoo() const`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `std::mem_fn` to achieve the same goal:

`Foo f;
std::function<int(Foo &)> getIntFoo = std::mem_fn(&Foo::getIfoo);
int ret = getIntFoo(f);`

or if you need pointer argument, std::function could resolve this for you:

`Foo f;
std::function<int(Foo *)> getIntFoo = std::mem_fn(&Foo::getIfoo);
int ret = getIntFoo(&f);`

boost have its own alternative